# How to see if business was in top/bottom 25th percentile in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, percentile

I have data that looks like the following:

```
business_id|business_name|  time_value  | time_bin |yoy_txn_growth
    1111   |     A       |  July 1,2022 |  Monthly |   .43
    2222   |     B       |  July 1,2022 |  Monthly |   .35
    1111   |     A       |  June 1,2022 |  Monthly |   .27
    2222   |     B       |  June 1,2022 |  Monthly |   .25
    1111   |     A       |  May 1,2022  |  Monthly |   .13
    2222   |     B       |  May 1,2022  |  Monthly |   .12
    1111   |     A       |  April 1,2022|  Monthly |   .09
    2222   |     B       |  April 1,2022|  Monthly |   .08
    1111   |     A       |  March 1,2022|  Monthly |   .20
    2222   |     B       |  March 1,2022|  Monthly |   .19
    1111   |     A       |  July 1,2022 | Quarterly|   .49
    2222   |     B       |  July 1,2022 | Quarterly|   .47
    1111   |     A       |  April 1,2022| Quarterly|   .02
    2222   |     B       |  April 1,2022| Quarterly|   .01
```

I'd like to know if for each time_value + time_bin if a business was in the top 25th percentile of yoy transaction growth and, separately if the business was in the bottom 25th percentile of yoy transaction growth. There may be many more businesses or there may be some cases as few as 1 in the whole table (when it would be true it was both in the top25 and the bottom25 to default).

```
business_id|business_name|  time_value  | time_bin |yoy_txn_growth| top25perc | bot25perc
    1111   |     A       |  July 1,2022 |  Monthly |   .43        |   TRUE    |   FALSE
    2222   |     B       |  July 1,2022 |  Monthly |   .35        |   FALSE   |   TRUE
    1111   |     A       |  June 1,2022 |  Monthly |   .23        |   TRUE    |   FALSE
    2222   |     B       |  June 1,2022 |  Monthly |   .25        |   FALSE   |   TRUE
    1111   |     A       |  May 1,2022  |  Monthly |   .13        |   TRUE    |   FALSE
    2222   |     B       |  May 1,2022  |  Monthly |   .12        |   FALSE   |   TRUE
    1111   |     A       |  April 1,2022|  Monthly |   .09        |   TRUE    |   FALSE
    2222   |     B       |  April 1,2022|  Monthly |   .08        |   FALSE   |   TRUE
    1111   |     A       |  March 1,2022|  Monthly |   .18        |   TRUE    |   FALSE
    2222   |     B       |  March 1,2022|  Monthly |   .19        |   FALSE   |   TRUE
    1111   |     A       |  July 1,2022 | Quarterly|   .46        |   TRUE    |   FALSE
    2222   |     B       |  July 1,2022 | Quarterly|   .47        |   FALSE   |   TRUE
    1111   |     A       |  April 1,2022| Quarterly|   .02        |   TRUE    |   FALSE
    2222   |     B       |  April 1,2022| Quarterly|   .01        |   FALSE   |   TRUE
```

How can I accomplish this in BigQuery?

Comment: Could you clarify how you are calculating the percentile?

Comment: I am not yet calculating the percentile, the last table is just for schema example purposes. How to calculate percentile is what I’m looking for.

Comment: Hi Mark McGown,  If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your requirement, [percentile_cont](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#percentile_cont) can be used for getting percentiles with [if](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions#if) condition. You can try below query to get the expected output.

**Query**

```
SELECT
 *,
IF
 (PERCENTILE_CONT(yoy_txn_growth,
     0.75) OVER(PARTITION BY time_bin, time_value) <yoy_txn_growth,
   TRUE,
   FALSE) AS top25perc,
IF
 (PERCENTILE_CONT(yoy_txn_growth,
     0.25) OVER(PARTITION BY time_bin, time_value)>yoy_txn_growth,
   TRUE,
   FALSE) AS bot25perc
FROM `project.dataset.Percentiletest`
ORDER BY time_value,time_bin
```

**Output**

[image]